# iOS inapp purchase subscription serverside validation security

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

The logic of the app.
You register with login password. Then if you doesn't have subscription (checked by server) you go to "Buy subscription page".

Problem.
I register user1. buy subscription. token1 goes to server.
I register user2. as he doesn't have subscription he goes to "Buy subscription page", clicks "Buy", apple says "You already bought subscription" and gives token2 (why does it give different token?)

```
var receiptUrl = NSData.FromUrl(NSBundle.MainBundle.AppStoreReceiptUrl);
return receiptUrl.GetBase64EncodedString(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.None);
```

token2 goes to server. As a result we have 1 bought subscription but 2 users that use the same subscription.
Is there any way to identify itunes of user? to save along the token and be able to check if that itunes user already bought subscription for some server side account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fundamental problem in StoreKit receipts and I think most developers don't realize it.

The problem is that Apple doesn't give developers a way to identify which iTunes account a receipt belongs to. This makes it trivial for a user to share their iTunes credentials with other users and unlock subscriptions.

The correct way to handle this is to, in your database, store the actual `transaction_id` from the Apple `verifyReceipt` response, and ensure it is unique in your database. This is a lot of work, so it may not be worth it.

It is further complicated by the fact that sometimes, you want an iTunes account to be usable with different app side accounts. For example if a user creates an account and purchases a subscription, lets the subscription expire, then later creates a new account and tries to purchase again, it should be permitted, even though the same receipt is now being used by multiple accounts.

If you don't want to deal with it, [I have a service](http://www.revenuecat.com/) that handles all these edge cases automatically.